# I am trying to workout bluetooth keyfinder with at tiny85

Tags: loops, if-statement, arduino

I am receiving a character"1" then buzzer should continuously sound **If** character "2" is received then the buzzer should **Off**

```cpp
void loop()
{    
    if (mySerial.available()) // there is some data to read
    {
        receivedChar = mySerial.read();

        if (receivedChar == '1') 
        {
            mySerial.println("Received a 1"); // for debugging
            digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
            tone(buz, 1000, 500);
        }

        if (receivedChar == '2')
        {
            mySerial.println("Received a 2"); // for debugging
            digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

but here buzzer is not looping or repeating. could you suggest any other. It is OK to fuction only buzzer no need of any LED to glow.

Comment: Does the LED change state in response to serial input? What serial settings did you use? This is presumably a Trinket as you're using Arduino API functions, so which pin is the buzzer connected to -- not all of them can do PWM and the tone generator needs to issue a PWM signal.

Comment: i am using at tiny85 there were no PWM pins left. pin 0 and 1 are used for Rx and Tx.